# how do I properly escape this regex string in swift to create a NSRegularExpression object?

Tags: swift, regex

the google maps API says to use this regex to find a valid google maps link, I can't seem to create a regex object with this string without it throwing an error, I have tried removing the backslashes but it still comes back as invalid

```
(http(s?)://)?
((maps\.google\.{TLD}/)|
 ((www\.)?google\.{TLD}/maps/)|
 (goo.gl/maps/))
.*
```

e.g.

```
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(http(s?)://)?((maps.google.{TLD}/)|((www.)?google.{TLD}/maps/)|(goo.gl/maps/)).*")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Try replacing: `{TLD}` with `com` - TLD stands for 'Top Level Domain'.

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes are crucial. A period without a backslash means *any character*. You have to add a second backslash respectively but there is a convenience syntax:

Wrap the literal string in `#`: (`#" ... "#`)

```
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"(http(s?)://)?((maps\.google\.{TLD}/)|((www\.)?google\.{TLD}/maps/)|(goo.gl/maps/)).*"#)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: it still isn't a valid regex :(

Comment: Of course you have to replace `{TLD}` with a top level domain like `com`